# Games eboard chess

Tags: unity

When I move a chess piece, the piece will not stay in the selected square.
I select Peer, Play against Engine, select Crafty or GNU chess. Page appears, click OK, then both page and chessboard disappears from the Ubuntu screen.
I downloaded Xboard for comparison and the file appears under Dash,but I don't know how to activate it. Same goes for any other downloaded file. I would like to move these files to the Launcher, but wonder if that would be enough to get them working.
I have achieved a passing familiarity with Ubuntu to date (windows XP past experience) and I suspect that I am lacking an understanding of how files,folders, programs work in Ubuntu, So any direction from the community will be helpful, I'm sure.
I upgraded to 14.04 yesterday and use GUI only. Command line usage is in the distant future, if at all.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug in `eboard` that you are seeing, 
you did nothing wrong.

I just tried what you did, and `eboard` crashed.

The bug was already reported at launchpad: [crash if select crafty engine](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eboard/+bug/1306419)

So, as the issue seems to depend on "Crafty", could you use something else as workaround?

Stack trace after starting `eboard` and selecting "Crafty" to play against:

```
$ eboard
*** buffer overflow detected ***: eboard terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x741cf)[0x7faf00bb21cf]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x5c)[0x7faf00c49b2c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x10a9f0)[0x7faf00c489f0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x10a10b)[0x7faf00c4810b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__snprintf_chk+0x78)[0x7faf00c48028]
eboard[0x4682c8]
eboard[0x467fc0]
eboard[0x43e1b9]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_closure_invoke+0x138)[0x7faf01c623b8]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(+0x21d3d)[0x7faf01c73d3d]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_signal_emit_valist+0xdd9)[0x7faf01c7ba29]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_signal_emit+0x82)[0x7faf01c7bce2]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(gtk_widget_activate+0x7c)[0x7faf025de4ec]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(gtk_menu_shell_activate_item+0xfd)[0x7faf024e104d]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(+0x13f39c)[0x7faf024e139c]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(+0x12d7e5)[0x7faf024cf7e5]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_closure_invoke+0x138)[0x7faf01c623b8]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(+0x21afb)[0x7faf01c73afb]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_signal_emit_valist+0xaa9)[0x7faf01c7b6f9]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_signal_emit+0x82)[0x7faf01c7bce2]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(+0x23d674)[0x7faf025df674]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(gtk_propagate_event+0xc4)[0x7faf024cdf94]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(gtk_main_do_event+0x2db)[0x7faf024ce34b]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0(+0x5922c)[0x7faf0214922c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_dispatch+0x254)[0x7faf01992e04]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x49048)[0x7faf01993048]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_loop_run+0x6a)[0x7faf0199330a]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(gtk_main+0xa7)[0x7faf024cd417]
eboard[0x40a6fe]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7faf00b5fec5]
eboard[0x40adb3]
```

Comment: I downloaded Xboard.4.7.3.tar.gz. Icon appears under Files & Folders. I click on the icon and a larger icon appears whick offers three choices: Open,Add files and Extract, none of which brings up the chessboard. I'm having trouble understanding some of the terminology in Ubuntu, but mainly I can't figure out how to activate (configure?) the downloaded software (programs? .For Volker Siegel